# Find Replace text FOO with Style “Heading 1” with <h1>Foo</h1>

Tags: html, find-and-replace, styles, microsoft-word-2016, accessibility

I am trying to find an easy way to convert my Word documents to HTML without the awful save-as that is built in. These are structured documents (designed for our screen-reader (JAWS) users), and so they use Heading 1, 2, 3, 4 & the Table of Contents.

We plan to convert these to DAISY audiobooks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAISY_Digital_Talking_Book ) , so we need pretty clean, but structured, HTML to convert.

I tried the find-replace, using Styles, but it would just replace anything in the text part of the search. I could convert it from any one style to another, but adding text in the box messed it up.

(I think I see that CSS for DAISY means that instead of just `<h2>` it will have to be `<level2 class=='section' <h2>` (and closing tags), but that's step 2 after I handle this part.)

I just want to be able to find any text using Style 2 and add text to the start of that line saying "yep, here's some style 2" so that I can do the HTML/CSS stuff.

Thanks!
*(I initially posted this in StackOverflow because I didn't know SuperUsers existed.  I would be happy adding a VBA thingie if that's the best solution, but if there's a simpler one, then that would be awesome too. Thanks again!)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656777/find-replace-text-foo-with-style-heading-1-with-h1foo-h1*

Comment: If you still have access to an older version of MS Word (especially version 2010 or 2013), I would recommend using the [Open XML to DAISY XML Translator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openxml-daisy/). Unfortunately, [this extension is not yet available for Office 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-the-Save-as-Daisy-add-in-for-Word-0dafec98-d478-479e-a4f2-dd22d2ef6d22).